# Clarification regarding linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider a matrix $A_{m\times n}$ with full column rank, and let $m>n$. I define a transformation $T:C(A^T) \to C(A)$ as $T(x) = Ax$ ($C(A^T)$ is the row space of $A$, $C(A)$ is the column space of A). Now, let $b \in C(A)$, then if there is an $x\in C(A^T)$ such that $Ax=b$ for some $b \in C(A)$, then such $x$ will be unique, since the matrix has full column rank. Therefore, $T$ is one-to-one.

I'm not very sure about onto, but here's my argument: I use the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ = $C(A^T) \oplus N(A)$, where $N(A)$ is the null space of $A$. Therefore, any solution $x$ for $Ax=b$ can be written as $x = x_r + x_n$, where $x_r \in C(A^T)$, $x_n \in N(A)$. For the given matrix $A$, $N(A) = \{0\}$, therefore every solution $x=x_r$.  Now, for every $b \in C(A)$, $Ax=b$ has a solution. Further, since every solution $x=x_r$, therefore, the transformation is onto.

From the above arguments, I concluded that the transformation is invertible. Is my reasoning correct? Also, what would be the matrix associated with this linear transformation; shouldn't it be $A$ itself?

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming $m>n$ $A$ cant possibly be invertible, as then $\Bbb R^m\cong \Bbb R^n$ via $A$, leading to the contradiction $m=n$...

Comment: @PrudiiArca I get your point, but could you please point out the flaws in my argument? Thank you.

Comment: I believe it to be $\Bbb R^n \cong C(A^T) \oplus N(A)$. I think it should be the column space of $A$. The columns of $A$ span the image, not its rows...